# select where id IN (list) not working after list modified

Tags: php, mysql

This seems like a very simple issue, but its causing me a ridiculous headache.

Here is my query: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ($list);`

Lets say the list is: `1,2,3,4,5,6`

On the first execution of the query, it works great, retrieves the requested rows.
Then, I remove one value: `1,2,4,5,6`

Suddenly, the query retrieves nothing.

I echo `$list` and `$list` displays `1,2,4,5,6`

I replace `IN ($list)` with `IN (1,2,4,5,6)` and it works perfectly.

What am I missing?

Heres the code that removes one value:

```
function removeFromList($id, $list){
$ider = ','.$id.',';
if($list[strlen($list)-1] == ','){
if($list[0] != ','){
    $list = ','.$list;
}
$list = str_replace($ider, ',', $list);
if($list[strlen($list)-1] == ','){
    $list[strlen($list)-1] = '';    
}
if($list[0] == ','){
    $list[0] = '';  
}
} else {
if($list[0] != ','){
    $list = ','.$list;
}
$list = $list.',';
$list = str_replace($ider, ',', $list);
if($list[strlen($list)-1] == ','){
    $list[strlen($list)-1] = '';    
}
if($list[0] == ','){
    $list[0] = '';
}
}
return $list;
}
```

Comment: Post your code?  There's probably something we're not seeing.

Comment: theres nothing else to see...

Comment: But obviously we can't help with this little information...

Comment: Can you post the code that "removes one value"?

Answer (score 0):

```
What happens if you change your query to this
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ('$list');
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `find_in_set()`:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE find_in_set(id, $list)
```

In the `in` statement the list represents the *single* value `1,2,3,4,5`.

The alternative is to create the SQL statement with the list in it directly:

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE id in (".$list.")"
```

This is more efficient, in the sense that the query can take advantage of an index on `id`.

Comment: I don't think you can pass a column name as the search string for: FIND_IN_SET (search string, string list)